# SOAP and HTTP Post

Tags: asp.net, web-services, http

I have an ASP.NET web service running that accepts both HTTP POST and SOAP requests. Are there any disadvantages to using a simple HTTP POST to get the data from the WS instead of using SOAP over HTTP?

I can't think of anything else other than the support for transmission of complex data types, and I don't think I'll need that in this project.

Thanks, 
Teja.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The clue is in the question...

> using a simple HTTP **POST** to **get** the data

A POST is not a GET, a GET is a GET.

If you're the only person operating on the WS then it's not a problem as long as you are handling your incoming connections properly. If it is open to outsiders then I would recommend sticking to conventions, they are there to save us from ourselves :)